# How to interpret "error C2018: unknown character '0x40'?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008

While compiling some code I receive the following:

"error C2018: unknown character '0x40'"

I wonder how to resolve such issue?

Comment: just out of curiosity, did you ftp the file from one OS (read *nix) to Windows. Looks to me to be an encoding problem.

Comment: It seems rather unlikely to be an encoding issue if the file otherwise compiles but gains an extra '@' sign. '@' isn't a "top bit set" character which rules out the common latinX <-> utf-8 issues that sometimes happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is where I would begin:

- Have you included any non-standard include files?  If so, check those for errors.
- Have you missed a semi-colon somewhere?
- Have you accidently used object > data instead of object -> data anywhere in your code?
- Have you copied the code from one machine (OS) to another, causing encoding issues?

Comment: Opened the file in another editor which showed the hidden characters.

Answer (score 4):

Character 0x40  is '@' in ascii, iso-8859-1, utf-8 and many other encodings. It's also not part of the basic character set in `C` so should not appear in your source except possibly in a character or string literal or a comment. How are you using it and what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

I've just got this error, but complaining about character '0x6', compiling a CPP file with Visual Studio 2010. And I got rid of it rewriting the line that was causing the error (writing the very same line above the old one, and deleting the old one).

Comment: I just got the same error now. Rewriting the whole line solved this. I am curious to know, why rewriting solved the problem.

Comment: Sometimes this error appears when using precompiled headers, even as of MSVC2015. This is certainly a bug; removing the corresponding options from the compiler command line mysteriously solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Open offending .c file in hex editor and search for 0x40. Maybe some unicode or utf8 string made it into ascii file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was simply in NOT including the header that contains #define MYSQL_VERSION_ID which was referred in offended code.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error with a TeamCity build.  I had a VS2013 generated resource file which was causing the error.  I found that the encoding was odd, which I could see in NotePad++.  So I **converted** the encoding to UTF-8 without BOM in NotePad++, which fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

My code was previously edited in XCode, and needed to be built in Visual Studio. In Visual Studio I found files with "._filename" but didn't see them in the explorer. Delete these and it should build!

Comment: For the record: i think macos is creating these hidden _ files ... not sure if that really answers the question.

Comment: Yeah that was the root of my problem. It doesn't seem like the most common cause for this VS error, but figured I would share it should someone else had a similar problem.